How to point to _TEB without redefining it?
I'm working on reverse engineering a game, which uses the Thread Local Storage Pointer from NTCurrentTeb to initialize a pointer to a game object.
The IDA output looks like this:
bool sub_51C3CC()
{
  int v0; // eax
  _BYTE *v1; // rdx

  v0 = 0;
  v1 = *(_BYTE **)(*(_QWORD *)NtCurrentTeb()->ThreadLocalStoragePointer + 568i64);
...

Currently, I've implemented it as
#include <cstdint>
#include <windows.h>


bool AcademyWon()
{
    int hasWon;
    uint8_t *threadPointer;

    hasWon = 0;
    threadPointer = *(uint8_t **)(*(intptr_t *)NtCurrentTeb()->ThreadLocalStoragePointer + 568);
}

The code above throws the error of "pointer or reference to incomplete type "_TEB" is not allowed", as _TEB is defined like this in winnt.h:
struct _TEB *
NtCurrentTeb (
    VOID
    )

{
    return (struct _TEB *)__readgsqword(FIELD_OFFSET(NT_TIB, Self));
}

Do I need to redefine _TEB in its entirety to point to it? Or is there any way to achieve the same result without touching it?

It is not necessary to define a struct type in order to create/return pointers to that type (e.g. null pointers).   It is, however, necessary, to define that type in order to dereference such a pointer, or to create an instance of that type.   Your AcademyWon() function is dereferencing, with NtCurrentTeb()->ThreadLocalStoragePointer + 568).   The -> operator is a pointer-dereferencing operator.     The usual way of handling such things is to place the struct definition in a header (not just a forward declaration) and #include that header in order to dereference such pointers.

C or C++ makes a difference here. It follows the common pattern of introducing a type alias for a struct: typedef struct _TEB { ... } TEB;. In C++ you can use either _TEB or TEB. In C you have to use struct _TEB or TEB. It is defined in winternl.h. The code you included doesn't define the structure. It defines the function NtCurrentTeb() which returns a struct _TEB aka TEB.

Thanks! It seems I misread the function, thinking that it's defining the structure instead of returning it. So in theory, defining the _TEB struct until ThreadLocalStoragePointer in a header file and then including it should resolve it?

Or, rather than going full low level just use TlsAlloc and associated functions (TlsFree, TlsGetValue, TlsSetValue) or even the compiler implementation. There's a good chance the original code didn't touch the TEB directly.

It absolutely didn't touch the TEB directly. That's a standard way to access a statically-allocated TLS value, and all that code was generated by a compiler. In the original code it was just a bog-standard access of thread_local global variable. Issue is, OP probably wants to retain functionality 100%, so that some parts of the original code could get replaced with new code and it all still works.

Unfortunately you cannot simply access _TEB::ThreadLocalStoragePointer because this field is not documented and not provided in Windows SDK. And you cannot redefine _TEB since it is probably already defined (and you don't really want to).
I can see two general approaches here.

You could declare some different structure with the same layout which contains fields you need:

struct MY_TEB { // or take a complete definition from Wine headers
    LPVOID Reserved[11];
    LPVOID ThreadLocalStoragePointer;
}
LPVOID tls = ((struct MY_TEB*)NtCurrentTeb())->ThreadLocalStoragePointer;


In case of ThreadLocalStoragePointer specifically: It is kind of defined in SDK's _TEB definition but not named. There's still a location in the structure which corresponds to this field, it is there for all the architectures (I think), so you could still use that:

LPVOID tls = NtCurrentTeb())->Reserved1[11];

